# Check Condition and then show input field in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a multistep form without livewire. In my form, I want the user to select the report type from the select box, what kind of report it will then show the input field accordingly. I don't understand how can I do it. I know there is many problem Please so me How can I check report type and then how can I show accordingly input field
[image: First Step]

Here input field will show

[image: Second Step]
This is my route

```
Route::get('/create/report', [AdminController::class, 'CreateReport']);
Route::post('/create/report', [AdminController::class, 'CheckReportType']);
```

This is my controller code

```
  public function CreateReport()
    {
        $data['fiscal_year'] = FiscalYear::all();
        $data['month'] = Months::all();
        $data['report_type'] = ReportType::all();
        $data['report'] = Report::all();
        return view('admin.create_report', $data);
    }
    public function CheckReportType(Request $request)
    {
        $report_type = $request->report_id;
    }
```

This is my view code

```
<option value="">Please select report type</option>
@foreach($report_type as $data)
<option value="{{$data->type_code}}"> {{$data->name}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>

@if($report->report_type == 1001)
<label>Student Name</label>
<input type="text" name="student_name"/>
 @else
<label>Teacher Name</label>
<input type="text" name="teacher_name"/>
  @endif
```

Please note that I intend to do this using a multi-step form. In the first step the user will select the report type and in the next step will show the input field.

Comment: You can use Javascript to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand If you don't want to use Javascript and this is a multistep form you can store the value in **Session** with key and in next step check the session key-value and apply conditions based on that.

Comment: Can you show me please how can I get value for report_type?

Comment: i am sorry but i seriously dont understand what do you mean like if you have to set the 
<select name="report_id">
<option value="">Please select report type</option>
@foreach($report_type as $data)
<option value="{{$data->type_code}}"> {{$data->name}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
if you pass this to controller you can get it like $request->report_id i cannot see your select opening tag but if you are missing that you need that and set its name to report_id